# How to split the data in single column to multiple column in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a thousands of entries in excel like this

1. A

2.Amber Blackwell

3.5899 Township Road

4.19 Glenford, Ohio 43739

5.Phone:XXXXXXXX

6.

7.

8.Alaska Communication / Robert Muncy

9.600 TELEPHONE AVE

10.ANCHORAGE, ALASKA 99503-6010

11.Phone:XXXXXXX

12.

13.

14.RED74 IT Support

15.1 STRAUBE CENTER BLVD

16.PENNINGTON, NJ 08534-1467

17.Phone:XXXXXXX

18.

19.

20.Guru Adivalli

21.1220 E Oak Street

22.Louisville, KY 40204

23.Phone:XXXXXXX

HOW TO TRANSFORM THEM INTO NAME IN 1st COLUMN ADDRESS IN 2nd COLUMN city in 3rd and phone number in 4th?
and also how to remove the text "phone:" so I can only have numbers xxxxxx in 4th column? 
Kindly answer separately for each questions

Name    Address City/State/Zip  Phone

Thanks,
Regards,
Ruban

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the content and use Transpose option from Paste special. Once you have transferred the content the data will be transferred to each column as you have mentioned.

Now for your 2nd query, use Text - Column from data menu for separating text "Phone", once you  have separated the column, you can keep the required column and delete the non required column

Comment: No What I meant was I should have the final file like this:        1.Amber blackwell 5899 Township Road 19 Glenford, Ohio 43739  2.Alaska Communication / Robert Muncy 600 TELEPHONE AVEANCHORAGE, ALASKA 99503-6010 Phone:XXXXXXX name in 1st column location in 2nd like that